# Type parameter that contains type parameter itself

Tags: scala, generics, type-parameter

For returning the status and key of a database insert, I created the following structure:

```
sealed trait InsertResult[+I] extends Product with Serializable

object InsertResult {
  case class Created[+I](insertedId: I) extends InsertResult[I]
  case object DuplicateKey extends InsertResult[Nothing]
}
```

The type parameter `I` is the type of the key that was created (e.g. `UUID`). If the insert succeds, a `Created[I]` is returned; in case of a duplicate key error, the `DuplicateKey` object is returned.

This works, but since the database adds more metadata than just the key, I want to replace `I` by `Entity[I, T]`, where `I` still is the key type whereas `T` represents the type of inserted object (so basically an `InsertResult[Entity[I, T]]`). However, I'm having trouble doing that, just replacing the type parameter gives me an error for parameter `insertedId` (`I` and `T` cannot be resolved).

How do the type and method signatures have to look when replacing `I` with `Entity[I, T]`?

Comment: it would be helpful to see the signature of the `insert` function you currently have in place, i.e. the function that returns `InsertResult`

Comment: it is still unclear what `T` actually is. you stated that `T represents the type of inserted object`. however from your comment it seems that the inserted object is in fact a subclass of Entity. so what is T?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. `Entity[I, T]` is a case class, the creation of an instance could look like `Entity(new UUID, new Foo)`. The signature of a concrete insert  implementation looks like `insert(e: Entity[UUID, Foo]): InsertResult[Entity[UUID, Foo]]` (at least that's the plan, depending on my problem with `InsertResult`). So `T` is an arbitrary type, not a subclass of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be enough for your use case?

```
case class Entity[I, T](id: I, obj: T)

sealed trait InsertResult[I, T] extends Product with Serializable

object InsertResult {
  case class Created[I, T](entity: Entity[I, T]) extends InsertResult[I, T]
  case object DuplicateKey extends InsertResult[Nothing, Nothing]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example

object Answer extends App {
  case class Entity[I, T](id:I, obj:T)

  sealed trait InsertResult extends Product with Serializable {}

  object InsertResult {
    case class Created[I, T](entity:Entity[I, T]) extends InsertResult
    case object DuplicateKey extends InsertResult
  }

  object Storage {
    var data = Map.empty[Any, Any]

    def insert[I, T](entity:Entity[I, T]):InsertResult =
      data.get(entity.id) match {
        case Some(_) => InsertResult.DuplicateKey
        case None =>
          data += entity.id -> entity.obj
          InsertResult.Created(entity)
      }
  }

  val entities = Seq(Entity(1, "foo"), Entity(2, "bar"), Entity(1, "foobar"))
  entities map Storage.insert foreach println
}
```